# How to solve app Hang and Crash issue on Client Machine :: Windows 8 store apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I had developed windows 8 app using c#,XAML.

Development is finished and app is sent to client.Now the problem is app crashing on the client machine crash is not reproducible at our end.So We told client to send us the event viewer log so that we can get some insight into it.

So client sent us below information regarding crash extracted from event viewer.

**The program SonyLiv.exe version 1.0.0.0 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel.
 Process ID: f54
 Start Time: 01cf4736b70ce3f2
 Termination Time: 35
 Application Path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\3B783157.SonyLIV_1.0.0.8_x64__rgtht6n7rete4\SonyLiv.exe
 Report Id: 19dfccdc-b32a-11e3-be7a-e9381cf07b0a
 Faulting package full name: 3B783157.SonyLIV_1.0.0.8_x64__rgtht6n7rete4
 Faulting package-relative application ID: App**

And Below are some details regarding above crash.

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Hang" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1002</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>101</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-03-24T07:58:41.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>16479</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>Ashwin</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>SonyLiv.exe</Data> 
  <Data>1.0.0.0</Data> 
  <Data>f54</Data> 
  <Data>01cf4736b70ce3f2</Data> 
  <Data>35</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\3B783157.SonyLIV_1.0.0.8_x64__rgtht6n7rete4\SonyLiv.exe</Data> 
  <Data>19dfccdc-b32a-11e3-be7a-e9381cf07b0a</Data> 
  <Data>3B783157.SonyLIV_1.0.0.8_x64__rgtht6n7rete4</Data> 
  <Data>App</Data> 
  <Binary>55006E006B006E006F0077006E0000000000</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Can anyone please help to understand the above information so that I can resolve this issue.

I am blocked at this issue from last 10 days. Please do guide me what is the problem.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

I know its late but still in case someone looking for solution for the same.

I too caught into similar issue. But I figure out that if my method application is not responding for 5sec Windows will kill the application.

So, what I did is made it run asyncronously.

In case you want to do stuffs on UI thread:

```
var ignored = Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () =>
{
    yourTimeConsumingMethod();
});
```

In case you want to do stuffs in Background (i.e. non UI operation) thread:

```
await Task.Run(() => yourTimeConsumingMethod());
```

NOTE: If you update UI stuff in second case, you will get "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread."